# Use data from get_context_data in form_valid method

Tags: django

How can i use value from dictionary context in form_valid?

eg.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
     context_data = super(ProductView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
     product_obj = Product.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
     user_id = product_obj.user_id
     user_obj = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
     context_data['email'] = user_obj.email
     return context_data

def form_valid(self, form, **kwargs):
    email = context_data['email'] # need use this value
    return super(ProductView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in template as hidden input:

```
<input type="hidden" id="id_email" name="email" value="{{ 'email' }}">
```

then in method:

```
def form_valid(self, form, **kwargs):
    email = form.data['email']
    return super(ProductView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Tanks for atention, thats sounds work, i dont test, but i avoid the "trick", i would do it in `view`

Comment: @MagicHat I don't think you can do it in `views` in a clean way, but if you do, then plz notify me, because I am very curious about it :)

Comment: Well, i think first thing is wrong(idk, still check) is the `form_valid` is called before `get_context_data, make sense given that `get_context_data`  adds the object being displayed to the template. So i think gona change to: from `form_valid` to `get_context_data`.. i mark you in the solution

Answer (score 0):

Tested with Django 3.2.

```
def form_valid(self, form, **kwargs):
    context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
    _email = context['email']
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:

```
def form_valid(self, form, **kwargs):
     context_data = self.get_context_data(form=form, **kwargs)
     email = context_data['email'] # need use this value
     return super(ProductView, self).form_valid(form)
```

but you can also do:

```
def form_valid(self, form, **kwargs):
    for email in Product.objects.filter(id=self.kwargs['pk']).values_list('user__email', flat=True)[:1]:
        context_data['email'] = user_obj.email
    return super(ProductView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Also, if you use ProductModelForm, on form_valid you can use:

```
def form_valid(self, form, **kwargs):
    if hasattr(form.instance, 'user'):
        context_data['email'] = form.instance.user.email
    return super(ProductView, self).form_valid(form)
```

django have many ways to do it :)

After comment from MagicHat

I like version with "form.instance.user.email"

but if you a really want to call get_context_data:

```
def form_valid(self, form, **kwargs):
    self.object = form.save(commit=False)
    context_data = self.get_context_data(form=form, **kwargs)
    email = context_data['email'] # need use this value
    return super(ProductView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: tks for atention Maxim, the first way, i get error: `'ProductView' object has no attribute 'object'` `users/views.py, line 154, in form_valid context_data = self.get_context_data(form=form, **kwargs) ` and  `users/views.py, line 140, in get_context_data context_data = super(ProductView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs) ` sounds like `form_valid` run before `get_context_data` . The seconde way, i have a query set in `get_context_data` so i dont want repeat that. The third way i dont have product model form